# Can't reach my home external IP address when using vpn to home network

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

I have a server at my parents' house running OpenVPN and I'm using a Raspberry Pi as a VPN router at my dorm, giving me access to local services from all my devices. Both the server and the pi can reach my parents' external IP address without any problem (as well as local addresses of course). All my other devices connected to the pi can reach local addresses on my parents' network like intended, but none of them can reach the external address. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I've not worked with a raspberry Pi yet, but as it acts as a router.

edit* I miss read a part, devices within the pi network can ping to devices in parents network and ISP.

so lets say, ping to parents local ip 192.168.X.X works, from Pi.
Getting to the External network the Pi has to forward that to your parrents network.

So static route from pi to your parents router should work.

Example, Pi = 192.168.5.0/28
Parents = 192.168.10.0/28
ISP = 10.0.0.1

device within Pi network wants to send traffic to 10.0.0.1
Device sends it to Pi.
Pi has to send to parents router.
parents router has to send to ISP.

as they are all in a different networks, you will have to route the traffic.

But I ain't no expert.

PS. if your able to send some more information, It'll be easyer to identify the problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I don’t see how a static route would help. I have a domain pointed to my parents’ network, let’s call it domain.com. The pi is connected to the server via domain.com, and any devices on my parent’s network can reach domain.com. Devices connected  to the pi’s subnet can reach any device on my parents’ LAN as well as the rest of the internet, but specifically not domain.com

Comment: Ahh, no then indeed that is not the problem.

If domain.com is on the server and devices from Pi network can in fact ping the server.

My following question. do you have wireshark and can you check the packet send when pinging your domain.com?

as I said i'm not an expert, wonder if on the devices of pi network the DNS server of Domain.com has to be set?

As i know of in cisco packet tracer I need to give it the IP of the DNS server. 

Problem is probably that packet is not send or wrongly send, or the DNS server somehow won't resolve the page to those clients.

Comment: Also what about devices from other networks? maybe a friend could try? So you can narrow down the problem and cause.

Comment: DNS doesn’t seem to be the problem either. I can resolve the IP address of the domain without any problem, but all requests to the domain/ip address time out. The domain is reachable from anywhere else